# Setting node to spawn randomly from an array of points and to fall at gradually faster speeds

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

**The result I am looking to achieve**: I am looking to spawn a node randomly from 3 different locations stored in an array. Once spawned, I would like the node to fall. Gradually over time, I would like to have the node fall at faster speeds.

**What I currently have**: The node spawns at a set location and falls like it should. The node currently doesn't spawn randomly and the speed at which it falls doesn't increase. I have an array written but it currently isn't functioning the way it should.

**Updated code**:

```
 var nodeDropTime:TimeInterval = 5

   func fallingNodeAction(){

        self.node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "node 2")
        self.node.zPosition = 1
        self.node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.node.size.height / 10.0)
        self.node.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        self.node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        self.node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

        nodeDropTime -= 1

        var nodePosition = Array<CGPoint>()

        nodePosition.append((CGPoint(x:400, y:475)))
        nodePosition.append((CGPoint(x:450, y:475)))
        nodePosition.append((CGPoint(x:500, y:475)))

        self.node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.nodeCategory
        self.node.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.boundary
        self.node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        let shuffledLocations = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: nodePosition) as! [CGPoint]

        self.node.position = shuffledLocations[0]

    }

    fallingNodeAction()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the random location, import 
`GameplayKit`, so you can use `arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray` on the array of `CGPoint`s to then choose the first item in the array as the location. The code:

```
let shuffledLocations = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: nodePosition) as! [CGPoint]

self.node.position = shuffledLocations[0]
```

Comment: Hi @Nik, I am sorry for the late reply. I have been very busy at work. When implementing the code, I get a minor error when adding the 2nd line of code in your answer. The error: Cannot assign value of type 'Any' to type 'CGPoint'

Comment: @P.Dane try adding `: CGPoint` right after shuffledLocations (on the first line) and tell me what that does

Comment: The error is gone, but when compiling there is a small issue saying:  Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Adding the :CGPoint got rid of the error but caused the code to not compile

Comment: Try adding  `as! CGPoint` after shuffling the array (end of first line)

Comment: I have added a picture in the original post of what I am seeing.

Comment: I meant to say this earlier: `as! [CGPoint]`. Hopefully that fixes some errors

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I was afk.  The code now compiles, but it does not currently spawn the node from the array of positions. I think I may need to implement a timer or SKAction to spawn the nodes randomly using two Integers?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not actually sure why that's happening. Can you update your code from your question so I can see where a problem might be?

Comment: Hi Nik, sorry for not getting back to you until now, I had to work longer than expected. I updated the original post to my current code.

Comment: Did you get any results from making it an SKAction? Is the function even being called?

Comment: Hi Nik, I apologize for not getting back to you sooner, I was on vacation. I created an SKAction and called the function and everything works great! Thank you so much for your help! I really do appreciate it.